# Inject generic ViewModel Dagger Hilt Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

Hi I want to inject generic ViewModel type in my BaseActivity, how do i solve that using Dagger Hilt.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
 abstract class BaseActivity<VM: BaseViewModel> : AppCompatActivity() {

@Inject
lateinit var viewModel: VM

}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Update 1

Here is the reply I was talking about from Hilt team:

> So @ViewModelInject is kind of a one way thing, similar to @AndroidEntryPoint in a way. It only gets Dagger dependencies into your class. It does not add your ViewModel to the object graph as a Dagger binding. In order to access your ViewModel in a provider or somewhere else, you still need to go through the normal Android APIs of getting a view model like using a ViewModelProvider.
>
> The reason we can't provide it into the graph is that we don't know what ViewModelStoreOwner you want to use it with.

You can find this comment [here](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1927#issuecomment-645685218).

---

#### Original Answer

I was trying to do this days ago, and I think I read it somewhere on internet that it is not possible for Hilt to do this (I couldn't find the link till now).

Normally in Java we create ViewModel like this:

```java
MyViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

We need to provide [ViewModelStoreOwner](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider#ViewModelProvider(androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner)) in `ViewModelProvider` constructor, and I learned that hilt cannot know which `ViewModelStoreOwner` you want `MyViewModel` to be created for.

So we will keep creating view models the old way, and in Kotlin you will stick to do it like this:

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
abstract class BaseActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()

}
```

Once I find that comment mentioning this from Hilt team, I will update the answer here.

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed for updating me, do update your answer once you find something on it

Comment: @SahilShokeen I just updated my answer with that comment I was talking about.